# Issue with frameworks header in my project

Tags: iphone, ios

I updated Xcode to the 4.3.1 version but now I don't know what's going on. When I compile my project, the compiler gives this error:

> Lexical issue : 'Availability.h' file not found

And in other old projects :

> Lexical issue'QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h' file not found

It's so strange! But how can I fix these errors?

I already removed frameworks and added them again, but nothing changed.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced this error ! I uninstall xcode then re install xcode 4.2 then update to 4.3 and worked !

try remove your current xcode with this code :

```
sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all
```

hope this works ...

Answer (score 0):

Select target file and go to build phase and see whether the QuartzCore/QuartzCore' framework file is present in 'Link binary with libraries' section. If not added the framework.

For Availability.h if it is present then re-write it once.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks ... Now quarts gone but still availability.h error appears !!!! I open the frameworks   In header folder all header files are dissappear !!

Comment: Add all the frameworks which are required. Availability is a class?

Comment: Delete the reference of the Availability.h file and add back to the project.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the Framework to every class you need it. The Prefix-Header is, how its name says, only a prefix.

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Have you added this Framework to the Build Phases or have you done this using copy and paste or drag and drop?